# ¿Por qué no puedo asignar un valor a una propiedad en Python con @property.setter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cuando intento asignar un valor a la variable `self.__valor`, usando el método `setter`,  recibo el error `'bool' object is not callable`, ya sea asignándola desde `__init__` o desde una instancia.

```
class Valor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__valor = False
        # self.estado(True)

    @property
    def estado(self):
        return self.__valor

    @estado.setter
    def estado(self, estado_celula):
        self.__valor = estado_celula

v = Valor()
```

Gracias a las respuestas he comprobado que aquí estaba el error...

```
# v.estado(True)
```

Y este es el código correcto:

```
v.estado = True
print(v.estado)
```

Con otros tipos también da error.

**El código es bastante simple, pero no consigo ver dónde está la "trampa"...**

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: v = Valor();
v.estado = True;
print(v.estado);        
Igual así te funciona

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuetra ayuda. Ha funcionado poniendo `v.estado = True` en vez de `v.estado(True)`. Simple, pero difícil de ver. ;D Por desgracia solo puedo marcar una respuesta como válida...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que desde el momento que has decorado algo con un `@property`, se opera una "magia" en la que sería muy largo entrar en detalle, pero que básicamente hace que se ejecute el getter cuando simplemente pones el nombre de la propiedad.

Es decir, en tu caso, aunque `estado()` es un método de la clase, el hecho de que lleve delante `@property` hace que simplemente poniendo `instancia.estado` se ejecute ese método y obtengas el valor retornado.

Esto te permite hacer cosas como:

```
v = Valor()
print("El estado es", v.estado)
```

Y la sintaxis `v.estado` es mágicamente convertida en una llamada al método `Valor.estado(v)`, el cual como se ve en tu código retorna un booleano.

Es más, puedes usar `v.estado` como parte de otras expresiones más complejas, como por ejemplo; `if v.estado and 2>0:` etc...

Sabiendo esto, piensa por un momento qué está ocurriendo en esta línea que te daba error:

```
v.estado(True)
```

Según lo antes dicho, la parte `v.estado` se convierte mágicamente en una llamada a un método, el cual retorna un booleano, en este caso de valor `False` pues ese era el valor por defecto de `self.__valor`. **Y es a ese booleano** al que después le intentas invocar con parámetro `True`. En esencia la línea interior equivale a: `False(True)`, lo cual explica el error. No puedes invocar un booleano como si fuera una función.

Lo que has intentado técnicamente no es un error de sintaxis, ya que puede tener sentido en otros contextos. Por ejemplo, podrías tener una clase en la que una propiedad sea un objeto "llamable" (una función o una clase), por lo que al acceder a esa propiedad podríamos tener un resultado sobre el que sí que tenga sentido intentar una invocación. Pero en este caso el tipo retornado por la propiedad no es llamable, y de ahí el error.

Entiendo que lo que intentabas era ejecutar el setter, pero al igual que el getter no se ejecuta explícitamente sino que ocurre "automágicamente", lo mismo ocurre con el setter cuando usas esa propiedad al lado izquierdo de una asignación. Es decir, tendrías que haber hecho:

```
v.estado = True
```

y eso causará que se ejecute el método setter de esa propiedad, recibiendo `True` como parámetro.

**Nota** Si quieres saber cómo funciona realmente la "magia" que ocurre detrás del telón, debes leer sobre el [Protocolo Descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), pues el decorador `@property` básicamente redefine el símbolo declarado a continuación (`estado` en tu caso) para que en vez de un método sea una instancia de un tipo especial de objeto llamado "descriptor", que es quien llamará realmente a los getters y setters (en colaboración con el intérprete y ciertos métodos especiales, de esos llamados "dunder" porque su nombre comienza y termina por `__`)

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es de como intentas cambiar el valor de la propiedad del objeto.

```
v = Valor()
v.estado = True  #  Cambia estado en el @property
print(v.estado)  #  Pide el valor en el @estado.setter
```

**Edito**

Yo en los tutoriales siempre de python el getter y setter siempre entendí que era así:

```
class Valor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__valor = False
        # self.estado(True)

    @property
    def estado(self):
        return self.__valor

    @estado.setter
    def estado(self, estado_celula):
        self.__valor = estado_celula

v = Valor()
v.estado = False
print(v.estado)
```

Aunque la función se llama igual dependiendo de lo que pidas el @property (getter) o el @funcion.setter (setter) hacen que realicen las funciones diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

tu problema es que tienes dos métodos estado que es el setter y la property,por lo que te dan conflicto, yo cambiaria el nombre del setter

```
def nuevo_estado(self, estado_celula):
    self.__valor = estado_celula
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).